# Updating Winform ListView control by one event handler that may be fired from several threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, listview, thread-safety

I have a "Win Form" application which listening to an event that may be raised from some different threads.

on that event i want to update a "List View" control. 
of course that i may need to use Invoke but my question is:
 Should i use lock on the function i will build to update the "List View" control or not?

Be a ware that i am updating the List View only by one function in the form and by only one event but more than one thread may raise the same event.

is it true that all the events that may be fired from all the threads will be handled by the main thread only so they will be executed one by one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you think the event could be fired at the same time from multiple threads, or at least get fired again before finishing the update then yes you should lock.

Something simple like:

```
lock(myListView) {
  updateMyListView();
}
```

should be enough.  Locking on the list view object should still let you edit it.

A word of warning, this won't keep other things from editing the list view, **only** code that has it's own `lock(myListView)` block will pay attention to the lock.

Comment: But isn't it true that all the events that may be fired from all the threads will be handled by the main thread only so they will be executed one by one?

Comment: Actually that is true, I had forgotten that.  Especially if you invoke whenever necessary it should end up on the main thread.  With that in mind it probably isn't important to use the lock statement, but it should also not cost anything (since it will never have to wait for anything to unlock).